# SVG printing issue with mozilla browser

Tags: asp.net, svg, printing, mozilla

I am struggling with an issue of missing content from 2nd page onward while printing the SVG in mozilla browser.

Actually I have SVG content in SVG file and I have used object tag to bind SVG in HTML page by using below code

```
<object  id="svgembed" type="image/svg+xml" width="770" height="2132" 
        data="large_print.svg"><p>No SVG viewer</p></object>
```

This SVG file draw image on browser and require 2 pages to show the content properly. but the problem is with printing of this SVG content. in printing, first page have content but second page is blank page.

Please Help!

Comment: Presumably https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=376033

Comment: Thanks Robert for your quick reply. Yes, this is exactly the issue for which i am looking for help. Do you know any workaround to resolve this concern. I am hoping to convert svg to image and then do the printing. If you can help me to move forward in correct direction then it will be good! Thanks

Comment: To convert SVG into image, I have tried SVG rendering engine (available on codeplex) and inkscape but both are not converting SVG correctly. SVG rendering engine populate black blank boxes and it seems that inkscape create svg elements without css. Please Help!